# sftp server implementaion with Python

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I need to implement sftp server using python. My requirement is to move the file from remote machine to my application using the sftp commands like

```
copy configurations sftp://<ipaddress>/<filename>
```

Is it possible to do with Paramiko. If so any code snippet or doc on how to accomplish it would be helpful.

Comment: Please clarify what is copy and configuration.

Comment: This is a command that will be executed in a switch or a router to copy the running/startup configurations

Answer (score -3):

The following code snippet demonstrates simple implementation of sftp client with **paramiko**

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('rsa.key')
>>> transport = paramiko.Transport(('localhost', 3373))
>>> transport.connect(username='username', password='password', pkey=pkey)
>>> sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
>>> sftp.listdir('.')
['File.txt', 'File2.txt']
```

Very simple SFTP server in python: [sftpserver 0.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sftpserver)

Comment: Hi, I am looking out for sftp server implementation.

Comment: Added link to sftpserver 0.2