# need to get a python sftp server running

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I have saw this post on stackoverflow [sftp server implementaion with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290974/sftp-server-implementaion-with-python)

I have tried setting up https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sftpserver , but i cannot seem to get it to work properly.

Like the stackoverflow post above, i am trying to develop a method to connect ssh to switches which i am able to do using paramiko, but then i need to be able to copy files/configs from the switchs back to the windows host where i am running my python script. i need to get a functioning python based sftp server running on my windows host that will accept connections from any sftp client like the switches. so i currently used the following code below to run sftp server in python on my windows host. i tested the connection from another windows host i am able to telnet to port 22 fine so i know the sftp server for python is running, when i run winscp from the other window host, it makes a connection but then times out.  i can setup an ftp python server and connect using ftp client fine so i know i don't have any type of network issue.

not sure what i am doing wrong when i am running the sftp server below in python? i don't know if my key is wrong , i followed the steps from the sftpserver link above and ran "openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /tmp/test_rsa.key" to create a key from an ubuntu host i had. i don't see that any username or password is required from the client side when i use winscp to connect.. here is netstat -aon output from windows so it is listening on 22 and telnet to it works from another host.

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7012

the code i am currently using i taken from the following:
https://gist.github.com/Girgitt/2df036f9e26dba1baaddf4c5845a20a2
so in short i need a functioning sftp server running on windows in python script, then use any non-python component like winscp or a switch to connect to the sftp server running on windows in python script?

```
import time
import socket
import optparse
import sys
import textwrap
import os
import paramiko

from sftpserver.stub_sftp import StubServer, StubSFTPServer

import threading

HOST, PORT = 'localhost', 22
BACKLOG = 10

class ConnHandlerThd(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn, keyfile):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._conn = conn
        self._keyfile = keyfile

    def run(self):
        host_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(self._keyfile)
        transport = paramiko.Transport(self._conn)
        transport.add_server_key(host_key)
        transport.set_subsystem_handler(
            'sftp', paramiko.SFTPServer, StubSFTPServer)

        server = StubServer()
        transport.start_server(server=server)

        channel = transport.accept()
        while transport.is_active():
            time.sleep(1)


def start_server(host, port, keyfile, level):
    paramiko_level = getattr(paramiko.common, level)
    paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko_level)

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(BACKLOG)

    while True:
        conn, addr = server_socket.accept()

        srv_thd = ConnHandlerThd(conn, keyfile)
        srv_thd.setDaemon(True)
        srv_thd.start()


def main():
    usage = """\
    usage: sftpserver [options]
    -k/--keyfile should be specified
    """
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=textwrap.dedent(usage))
    parser.add_option(
        '--host', dest='host', default=HOST,
        help='listen on HOST [default: %default]')
    parser.add_option(
        '-p', '--port', dest='port', type='int', default=PORT,
        help='listen on PORT [default: %default]'
        )
    parser.add_option(
        '-l', '--level', dest='level', default='INFO',
        help='Debug level: WARNING, INFO, DEBUG [default: %default]'
        )
    parser.add_option(
        '-k', '--keyfile', dest='keyfile', metavar='FILE',
        help='Path to private key, for example /tmp/test_rsa.key'
        )

    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    options.keyfile = "C:\\test_rsa.key"

    if options.keyfile is None:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(-1)

    start_server(options.host, options.port, options.keyfile, options.level)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6):

i figured it out. my key file

had

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
MIEdksjdlfaj;slkdfj.........
.....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
in it.

i had to change both to

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
MIEdksjdlfaj;slkdfj.........
.....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

then winscp prompted for it fine